# Invalid changeset UUID Wordpress

Tags: permissions

Login as Administrator and when I click the stopkeeper theme customization, I got ***Invalid changeset UUID*** error and redirect to page and show as

> Cheatin’ uh?
>
> Sorry, you are not allowed to customize this site.

When I search the google, i got a solutions for **Non-existent changeset UUID** to check the site url and home url same in settings -> general.

But I didn't know how to solve this Invalid changeset UUID. Is any way to regenerate it

Note: the customizer loads and later it redirect to cheatin' uh page.